# Why is a fountain pen called 万年筆?

Tags: words, etymology

I am curious about the etymological history of 万年筆{まんねんひつ}, whose actual meaning is a fountain pen in Japanese.

If we separate the kanjis we have :

> 万{マン}: ten thousand
>
> 年{ネン}: years
>
> 筆{ヒツ}: brush

So, literally it means *a ten thousand years brush*, isn't it ?

Why is it called that way ? Is it because this item made its appearance at some point in History ten thousand years after another event ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

百, 千, and 万(萬) all have 'many' as part of their definitions. Going in order of lower number to higher number signifies a higher quantity. These numbers are often used figuratively, such as 万歳{ばんざい}（萬歳）signifying 'long life', while literally meaning 10,000 years (of age). 万 is often used in the figurative sense to convey something similar to permanence or eternity, though not quite in the literal sense.

[百](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%99%BE) very many; lots. Advanced age.
[千](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8D%83) many; numerous; very.
[万](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%87) myriad; many; all; a large number; everything

In the case of the naming of 万年筆, one would assume that it was mostly a marketing device, giving the impression to the buyer that it would last indefinitely.

Comment: [万年](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/210550/meaning/m0u/) is a kind of idiom: 万年雪 = permanent snow, 万年カレンダー = perpetual calendar